# Related products shows category wise

Tags: product

In product details page we can get related products easily. But I want to show those related products in category wise.

Comment: What do you mean by "category wise"? Grouped by category, one some categories shown or something else.

Comment: Like Category1
 Product1
 Product2

Category2
 Product3
 Product4, where Product1, Product2, Product3, Product4 are related products. But, I want to show those their category wise(like Category1, Category2)

Comment: so what have you tried so far?

Comment: Related products are tied to a product, not to a category. You can get all the related products from a category, but that will take you some time and resources. I added a solution in my answer which might be the correct one for you.

Answer (score 1):

A simple solution for this is doing a "featured" attribute per product and show only the product with that attribute in the frontend, filtered by the current category.
This is not a core feature of Magento, but it can be easily achieved with something like this:

```
$_category  = $this->getCurrentCategory();
$current_level = $_category->getLevel(); 
$collection = $_category->getCollection(); 

$collection->addAttributeToSelect('url_key')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('name')
            ->addAttributeToSelect('parent_id')
            ->addAttributeToFilter('featured', 1)
            ->addAttributeToFilter('level',array('in'=>array($current_level+1,$current_level+2)))
            ->setOrder('position','ASC')
            ->load();
```

Source [here.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14151594/filter-a-magento-category-collection-by-a-product-attribute)

Guide to create attributes [here](http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/tutorial-creating-attributes-custom-fields).

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$related = Mage::registry('current_product')->getRelatedProductIds();
$categoryShow = 2; // id of category wise
foreach ($related as $productId) {
    $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($productId);
    $categoryIds = $product->getCategoryIds();
    foreach ($categoryIds as $categoryId) {
        /*
         * if category wise id is dinamic
         * $catefory = Mage::getModel('catalog/product')->load($categoryId);
         * change the 'if' if ($category->getName() == 'wise')
         * 
         */
        if ($categoryId == $categoryShow) {
            // show the product
        }           
    }
}
?>
```